# Select max,min, last value from a column in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

table format

```
id   time_stamp
3    2013-09-05 12:00:00
5    2013-09-06 12:00:00 
12   2013-09-07 12:00:00
2    2013-09-08 12:00:00
5    2013-09-09 12:00:00
8    2013-09-10 12:00:00
```

From the above table i want select min(id), max(id), last id, last time_stamp in **single mysql select query statement**

Needed output is:

```
min   max  last(val)  last(time_stamp)
2     12   8          2013-09-09 12:00:00
```

i used following Query

```
select id, min(id),max(id), time_stamp from table order by time_stamp limit 1
```

***I am getting wrong latest id value 3 instead of 8***

Check this if below SQL fiddle
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9cb1/2/0

Comment: Order your time stamp in descending order. Otherwise you are getting the first row which is 3.

Comment: @GJay you have the last(time_stamp) mentioned incorrectly?

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9cb1/17

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Assuming you mentioned the last(time_stamp) incorrectly in your question** - Get the max, min as usual and then find out the last id and time stamp in a subquery which you can then JOIN to get all result in one row.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80d99/7)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (id int, time_stamp datetime);

insert into  t values(3,    '2013-09-05 12:00:00');
insert into  t values(5,    '2013-09-06 12:00:00');
insert into  t values(12,   '2013-09-07 12:00:00');
insert into  t values(2,    '2013-09-08 12:00:00');
insert into  t values(5,    '2013-09-09 12:00:00');
insert into  t values(8,    '2013-09-10 12:00:00');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT MIN(t.id), MAX(t.id), latest.id, latest.time_stamp
FROM t  JOIN (
  SELECT t.id, t.time_stamp
  FROM t
  ORDER BY time_stamp DESC
  LIMIT 1) latest
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80d99/7/0)**:

```
| MIN(T.ID) | MAX(T.ID) | ID |                       TIME_STAMP |
|-----------|-----------|----|----------------------------------|
|         2 |        12 |  8 | September, 10 2013 12:00:00+0000 |
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is a method, using the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
select min(id), max(id),
       substring_index(group_concat(id order by time_stamp desc), ',', 1) as lastid
from table ;
```